# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I hit the API, I get the response as

```
{"headers":{"Keep-Alive":["timeout=4, max=500"],"Server":["Apache"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Connection":["Keep-Alive"],"Vary":["X-Forwarded-For"],"X-XSS-Protection":["1;mode=block"],"Content-Length":["451"],"Content-Type":["application/hal+json"]},"statusCodeValue":200,"body":"{\"id\":\"7199\",\"username\":\"johntest@example.com\",\"start_time\":1583212261,\"expire_time\":1583253338,\"sponsor_profile\":\"1\",\"enabled\":false,\"current_state\":\"disabled\",\"notes\":null,\"visitor_carrier\":null,\"role_name\":\"[Guest]\",\"role_id\":2,}
```

Then I try to fetch the body.I get till body but I m not able to fetch username under body.Basically my main aim is to get the username.It throws this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
```

Logic that I tried to get username.

```
ResponseEntity<String> resp = restTemplate.exchange(
                            reader.getAccountURL() + request.getUsername(),
                            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
JSONObject accountDetails = new JSONObject(resp);
Object getBody =  accountDetails.get("body");
Object alreadyExits = ((JSONObject) getBody).get("username");
```

What m I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `getJsonObject("body")` instead of `get("body")` .

Comment: It looks like the response you have is a JSON-ification of a HTTP response. Therefore the body is simply a string value taht encodes another JSON object, so you'll need to parse the `body` value again.

Comment: @Arnaud When I do that I get this exception org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["body"] is not a JSONObject.

Comment: @JoachimSauer.Can you show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the steps:

1. get body string: `String bodyString= resp.getString("body");`
2. parse bodyString to jsonObject: `JSONObject body= new JSONObject(bodyString);`
3. get the username: `String usename= body.getString("username");`

This should work.

Comment: I am assuming, your `body` is string of valid json object

Comment: I tried it but it thows me an error saying username not found

Comment: print what you get in your body string, see if it contains `username` and better share your code and output

Comment: It does contain username.I have shown it in my post.

Comment: this shouldn't happen. Did you try the way I said above? if yes,can you share your code and error stacktrace please?

Comment: Thanks. It works! my bad I made a silly mistake before and that is why it was throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject is nothing but a map which works on key-value.
If the value returned by a key is map(i.e. key-value pairs) then it can be cast into a JSONObject, but in your case  `getBody.get("username")` returns `johntest@example.com` which is a simple string and not a key-value pair hence you get this exception
Use: `JSONObject getBody = accountDetails.getJsonObject("body")`
or you can use:

```
String bodyString= accountDetails.getString("body");
JSONObject getBody= new JSONObject(bodyString)
```

and then use `Object alreadyExits = ((String) getBody).get("username");` and it should work just fine.

Comment: when I try it gives me this:The method get(String) is undefined for the type String

Comment: you have to make body also into jsonobject for which i have updated my answer

Comment: I tried it but I get the same error which I mentioned in my post

Comment: The json mentioned in the post is not a valid json, so can you please give the correct json so that it can be debugged..you can validate it on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/